# Fourth texture = segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I keep on getting **segmentation fault** each time I **load fourth texture** - what type of texture, I mean filename, does not matter. I checked value of `GL_TEXTURES_STACK_SIZE` which turned out to be **10** so quite more than **4**, isn't it?

Here're code fragments:

funciton to load texture from *png*

```
static GLuint gl_loadTexture(const char filename[]) {
    static int iTexNum = 1; 
    GLuint texture = 0;
    img_s *img = NULL;

    img = img_loadPNG(filename);
    if (img) {
        glGenTextures(iTexNum++, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, img->iGlFormat, img->uiWidth, img->uiHeight, 0, img->iGlFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img->p_ubaData);
        img_free(img); //it may cause errors on windows
    } else printf("Error: loading texture '%s' failed!\n", filename);

    return texture;
}
```

actual loading

```
static GLuint textures[4];

static void gl_init() {
    (...) //setting up OpenGL

    /* loading textures */
    textures[0] = gl_loadTexture("images/background.png");
    textures[1] = gl_loadTexture("images/spaceship.png");
    textures[2] = gl_loadTexture("images/asteroid.png");
    textures[3] = gl_loadTexture("images/asteroid2.png"); //this is causing SegFault no matter which file I load!
}
```

Any ideas?

Problem is present on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Maybe a stupid guess : are you sure that the file `images/asteroid2.png` exists ? Can you try to compile in Debug Mode (adding the -g3 flag in the CFLAGS under Linux) and tell us where exactly it stops ? I'd suggest you to use Valgrind if you still can't find out what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but change this:

```
glGenTextures(iTexNum++, &texture);
```

into this:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
```

[Here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenTextures.xml) is written:

> void glGenTextures( GLsizei n, GLuint* textures );
>
> n - Specifies the number of texture names to be generated.
>
> textures - Specifies an array in which the generated texture names are stored.

You are generating 1,2,3,4,... texture names instead of one, so `glGenTextures()` is trying to write to array ( `texture[0]` - `texture[3]` ), but you are passing single element `GLuint texture = 0;`, so you get segmentation fault.

And, please delete [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12338950/1569168) double post.